# Fyne testing: how do I test dialogs?

Tags: go, fyne

I want to make GUI testing, but investigation of `test` package and sources of `fyne` disappoints a lot.

Could somebody please tell, is there a way to fill text fields of a created dialog and click 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons to check results?

All docs I saw only suggest to move creating of form fields out to a `func` and check them out then individually, and, yes, that's an option, but is there a possibility to check it out as a complete dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I implemented an approach which does everything what I need.

@andy.xyz mb it would be useful to implement this out of the box.

Instead of calling `dialog.NewForm` directly I do this:

```golang
var newForm = dialog.NewForm
```

and afterwards I call `newForm` with the same arguments, as follows:

```golang
    name := widget.NewEntry()
    eName := widget.NewFormItem("Name", name)
    active := widget.NewCheck()
    eActive := widget.NewFormItem("Active", active)
    d := newForm("A dialog", "OK", "Cancel", []*widget.FormItem{eName, eActive}, func(b bool) {}, w)
```

A test looks like this:

```golang
    newForm = testNewForm

    assert.Equal(t, "A dialog", lastTestDialog.getTitle())
    assert.Equal(t, "OK", lastTestDialog.getConfirm())
    assert.Equal(t, "Cancel", lastTestDialog.getDismiss())

    lastTestDialog.setText(t, "Name", "some name")
    lastTestDialog.setCheck(t, "Active", true)
    lastTestDialog.tapOk()
    assert.Equal(t, false, lastTestDialog.isValid())
    // other checks
```

And here's the code of the implementation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "testing"
)

type testDialog struct {
    title    string
    confirm  string
    dismiss  string
    widgets  map[string]fyne.CanvasObject
    callback func(bool)
    invalid  bool
}

func (d *testDialog) Show() {}

func (d *testDialog) Hide() {}

func (d *testDialog) SetDismissText(string) {}

func (d *testDialog) SetOnClosed(func()) {}

func (d *testDialog) Refresh() {}

func (d *testDialog) Resize(fyne.Size) {}

func (d *testDialog) MinSize() fyne.Size {
    return fyne.Size{}
}

func (d *testDialog) getTitle() string {
    return d.title
}

func (d *testDialog) getConfirm() string {
    return d.confirm
}

func (d *testDialog) getDismiss() string {
    return d.dismiss
}

func (d *testDialog) isValid() bool {
    return !d.invalid
}

func (d *testDialog) tapOk() {
    d.invalid = false
    for _, wi := range d.widgets {
        if w, ok := wi.(fyne.Validatable); ok {
            if e := w.Validate(); e != nil {
                d.invalid = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if !d.invalid {
        d.callback(true)
    }
}

func (d *testDialog) tapCancel() {
    d.callback(false)
}

func (d *testDialog) setText(t *testing.T, name string, text string) {
    wi, ok := d.widgets[name]
    if !ok {
        t.Fail()
        return
    }
    e, ok := wi.(*widget.Entry)
    if !ok {
        t.Fail()
        return
    }
    e.SetText(text)
}

func (d *testDialog) setCheck(t *testing.T, name string, check bool) {
    wi, ok := d.widgets[name]
    if !ok {
        t.Fail()
        return
    }
    c, ok := wi.(*widget.Check)
    if !ok {
        t.Fail()
        return
    }
    c.Checked = check
}

func (d *testDialog) tapButton(t *testing.T, name string) {
    t.Helper()
    wi, ok := d.widgets[name]
    if !ok {
        t.Errorf("there's no widget with name %s", name)
        return
    }
    b, ok := wi.(*widget.Button)
    if !ok {
        t.Errorf("widget '%s' isn't a button", name)
        return
    }
    b.OnTapped()
}

var lastTestDialog *testDialog = nil

func testNewForm(title, confirm, dismiss string, items []*widget.FormItem, callback func(bool), _ fyne.Window) dialog.Dialog {
    widgets := make(map[string]fyne.CanvasObject)
    for _, i := range items {
        widgetsForItem := digWidgets(i.Widget)
        l := len(widgetsForItem)
        if l < 1 {
            continue
        }
        if l == 1 {
            widgets[i.Text] = widgetsForItem[0]
            continue
        }
        for x, wi := range widgetsForItem {
            widgets[fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", i.Text, x)] = wi
        }
    }
    lastTestDialog = &testDialog{title: title, confirm: confirm, dismiss: dismiss, widgets: widgets, callback: callback}
    return lastTestDialog
}

func digWidgets(root fyne.CanvasObject) []fyne.CanvasObject {
    if cnt, ok := root.(*fyne.Container); ok {
        var widgets []fyne.CanvasObject
        for _, o := range cnt.Objects {
            widgets = append(widgets, digWidgets(o)...)
        }
        return widgets
    }
    return []fyne.CanvasObject{root}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test package does not include anything specific for interacting with dialogs. Mostly you interact with each window specifically, the code works out much simpler.

Maybe something has been missed - feel free to provide more info here or open an issue on the GitHub project.

Comment: Ok, let's consider a simple dialog like this (sorry for markup, it breaks it all):
```go
func exampleDialog(w fyne.Window) {
 name := widget.NewEntry()
 eName := widget.NewFormItem("Name", name)
 d := dialog.NewForm("A dialog", "OK", "Cancel", []*widget.FormItem{eName}, func(b bool) {
  _ = os.WriteFile("tmp", []byte(name.Text), 0644)
 }, w)
 d.Show()
}
```
And I want to test that user has possibility to enter necessary info and get reasonable result. How do I do this?

Comment: It is not clear from your example what “necessary info” or “reasonable result” are, sorry. Can you explain more what you look to verify?

Comment: Consider also that you could test using the simpler Form widget in your unit tests (using the same FormItem[]), the dialog is just for presentation style/workflow I think.

Comment: Ok, for this example I mean to test full dialog cycle: 1) to fill the field with a test value, 2) to press the submit button so that the assigned function works, and 3) to check whether file with given test value has been written. and, in opposite, 1) to fill the field, 2) to press the cancel button, 3) to check the file has not been written.

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong, Fyne is a great thing, it looks like it is the only usable GUI lib for Golang, and I realize that it is in development state, so I don't even think to abuse or revile it somehow =)

Comment: Ah yeah a workflow test for dialog may not be added yet. I’d recommend opening an issue so the team can add it to the backlog.

Comment: Added one https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/2771